# Time taken by a cpp method in the Android Framework

Tags: android, c++, c, execution-time

How can I achieve to get the execution time of a C++ method in the Android framework?

Will the gettime of the day or getsystem time call be suitable?

I dont wan't the timer to take the extra time by itself, I rather want the exact time taken by the method (may by inserting start and end time at the start and end of the method and then taking the difference).

Comment: How is [tag:c] relevant here? Also, could you clarify what is "method"? I don't think C++ standard defines that term.

Comment: method inside the Android Framework could by made up of c(native) or c++.

Comment: do you need a profiler for the native code?

Comment: I still don't think it has anything to do with C. If you are writing C++, then [tag:c] is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @blackbelt yes kind of, but basically a start and end timer kind of method(what will be those methods is the question).

Comment: you should give http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/ a try

Comment: @blackbelt i am trying to use it for non native method.Kindly see the original Question .

Comment: for non native code you should use the profiler shipped with the android-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self Explanatory Code Snippet:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval start, end, diff;
::gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
function(); // Whose Execution time to measure
::gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
timersub(&end, &start, &diff);
```

diff.tv_sec - gives you seconds  and
diff.tv_usec - gives you microseconds

I would suggest this [link: High Precision Timing ...](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/171774/getting_high_precision_timing_on_.php?print=1) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For example this will return current time in milliseconds so you can call it in the beginning of your method and in the end of your method and calculate the difference. It works in Android  native layer

```
#include <time.h>
uint64_t ticks_ms()
{
    timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, 0);
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(t.tv_sec) * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
}
```

Comment: actually I am not looking to find the latency for the native method.Still this holds true for non native c++ method.

Comment: On the Java side you can use System.currentTimeMillis()